# How to add style to Example Values in Swagger 3.0 with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-3.0

I want to add styles and colors to the example values, just like the one Swagger has as example [here](https://petstore.swagger.io/):

[image]

Comment: How its displaying right now on your app?

Comment: The colors are defined in the swagger-ui.css. Can you confirm if `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css` is loaded on your swagger-ui html page?

Comment: Also, see this example on how to use swagger-ui v3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64778462/607637

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have configured Swagger 3 successfully, I can see the UI and the CSS file there, I managed to setup custom example values and defined field data types but still no colors...

Comment: can you share a reproducible example?